# Eclipse plugin: toggle menu command fails to find handler

Tags: eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I am trying to use toggle menu option but probably doing some mistake. Following code created toggle menu item and When I click this option for the first time after loading, it works fine but when I click again to toggle it back to old state, I get following error:

```
org.eclipse.core.commands.NotHandledException: There is no handler to execute for command my.commands.compileAutomatically
    at org.eclipse.core.commands.Command.executeWithChecks(Command.java:485)
    at org.eclipse.core.commands.ParameterizedCommand.executeWithChecks(ParameterizedCommand.java:508)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.HandlerService.executeCommand(HandlerService.java:169)
    ....
```

Menu:

```
<command
    commandId="my.commands.compileAutomatically"
    label="Compile Automatically"
    style="toggle">
</command>
```

Command:

```
<command
    defaultHandler="my.handlers.CompileAutomaticallyHandler"
    id="my.commands.compileAutomatically"
    name="Compile Automatically">
    <state
        class="org.eclipse.ui.handlers.RegistryToggleState:true"
        id="org.eclipse.ui.commands.toggleState">
    </state>
</command>
```

Handler:

```
public class CompileAutomaticallyHandler extends AbstractHandler {

    @Override
    public Object execute(ExecutionEvent event) throws ExecutionException {
        Command command = event.getCommand();
        boolean oldValue = HandlerUtil.toggleCommandState(command);
        System.out.println(oldValue);
        return null;
    }
}
```

Could somebody help me understand what is wrong with my code that it finds handler only once regardless of current menu state?
thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try to override isHandled() and return false in CompileAutomaticallyHandler.